# How to calculate grade of student using tsql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario like this,

```
 Studentid|Subject1|Subject2|Subject3|Subject4|Subject5|Grade

   1      |   1    |    1   |   1    |   1    |    1   |
   2      |   1    |    2   |   2    |   2    |    3   |
   .....etc
```

The table shows,student id and their rank in each sujects.I want to update grade column,based on the following condition,

1)if all subjects ranks are 1,then grads should be A
2)if any 3 ranks are 1,and other 2 subjects are having rank as 2, then B
3)if any 3 ranks are 2,and other 2 subjects are having rank as 3, then c

etc...Like this many condition can come.so i just want to know the solution approach.

Is it possible to write single query?

Comment: Can you normalize your schema?

Comment: Of course this type of information should never be in one table with columns subct1, subject2, etc. It is much harder to do calculations this way than ifyou use a normalized structure.

Comment: We need better requirements. What if I have 5 2s? 4 2s and a 1? 4 1s and a 2? You can't just say etc. and you can't only give requirements for three of the possible 5!+ permutations. Is there a math equation you're leaving out of the question?

Comment: Agree, with RedFilter - what you're wanting to do is very complicated based on your table layout. Normalizing your tables would make it simpler. Table1 might be composed of StudentID and Grade columns, while Table2 might be composed of StudentID, SubjectNumber, and Rank

Comment: If i normalize this table according to David's view, how can i write the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unpivot table to calculate grade:

```
;with 
Subject1 as (
  select Studentid, 1 as SubjectCode, Subject1 as subjectResult
  from your_table
),
Subject2 as (
  select Studentid, 2 as SubjectCode, Subject2 as subjectResult
  from your_table
),
...
Subject5 as (
  select Studentid, 5 as SubjectCode, Subject5 as subjectResult
  from your_table
),
subjects as (
   select * from Subject1 union all
   select * from Subject2 union all
   ...
   select * from Subject5

) 
select 
   Studentid, sum( subjectResult )
from
   subjects
group by
   Studentid
```

Notice that in last select you can calculate grade with a `case` statement.
Also you can upgrade `Grade` column with little changes:

```
...),
subjects as (
   select * from Subject1 union all
   select * from Subject2 union all
   ...
   select * from Subject5

), 
grades as (
 select 
   Studentid, sum( subjectResult ) as grade
 from
   subjects
 group by
   Studentid
)
update t set grade = grades.grade
from your_table t 
inner join grades on t.Studentid = grades.Studentid
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with all the other comments, it's a poor way to store the data. But if you're stuck and have to work with it then something like this could work:

```
UPDATE StudentsTable
SET StudentsTable.Grade = CASE 
    WHEN Tally.Total < 8
        THEN 'A'
    WHEN Tally.Total < 13
        THEN 'B'
    ELSE 'C'
    END
FROM StudentsTable AS St
JOIN (
    SELECT StudentID,
    Subject1 + Subject2 + Subject3 + Subject4 + Subject5 AS [Total]
FROM StudentsTable
) AS Tally
    ON St.StudentID = Tally.StudentID
```

Modify the CASE statement as desired. It's not pretty but it should do the trick.

Comment: Of course this is based on the very basic summing of scores to get grade. If there's more complicated logic involved you'll need to modify (and the above may not be usable dependant on complexity)

Answer (score 0):

I used UNPIVOT:

```
CREATE TABLE s
    (
      Studentid INT ,
      Subject1 INT ,
      Subject2 INT ,
      Subject3 INT ,
      Subject4 INT ,
      Subject5 INT ,
      Grade CHAR(1)
    )

INSERT INTO [s] VALUES 
(   1      ,   1    ,    1   ,   1    ,   1    ,    1   , ''),
(   2      ,   1    ,    2   ,   2    ,   2    ,    3   , '')

WITH cte AS (
SELECT u.StudentID, AVG(u.[g]) AS [grade]
from (SELECT * FROM [s]) AS [f]
UNPIVOT (g FOR [SUBJECT] IN (Subject1, Subject2, Subject3, Subject4, Subject5)) AS [u]
GROUP BY u.StudentID
)
UPDATE [s]
SET [Grade] = CASE
    WHEN c.[grade] <=1 THEN 'A'
    WHEN c.[grade] <=2 THEN 'B'
    WHEN c.[grade] <=3 THEN 'C'
    WHEN c.[grade] <=4 THEN 'D'
    ELSE 'F'
END
FROM [cte] AS [c]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[s]
    ON [c].StudentId = [s].[Studentid]
```

As others have stated, your grading metric is a little ambiguous, but I took a guess. If it's different, change as you see fit.